# how to design vertical custom JProgressBar

Tags: java

I have written this code for custom JProgressBar in which "string painted" appears just after the progress line, but I want the same functionality in a vertical JProgressBar, please tell how can I do that???

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;



public class R {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        new R();
    }

    public R() throws Exception {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        CustomProgressBar b = new CustomProgressBar();
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b.setStringPainted(true);
        f.add(b);
        f.setVisible(true);

        for(int i=0; i<101; i++) {
            b.setValue(i);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    }

}



class CustomProgressBar extends JProgressBar{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isStringToBePainted = false;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if(isStringToBePainted ) {
            Dimension size = CustomProgressBar.this.getSize();
            int x = (int)( size.width * CustomProgressBar.this.getPercentComplete() );
            int height = g.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
            int d = g.getFontMetrics().getDescent();
            int y = (size.height + height)/2-d;
            String text = getString();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK );
            g.drawString(text, x, 12);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setStringPainted(boolean b) {

        isStringToBePainted=b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd call `getOrientation()` and compare the results to `SwingConstants.VERTICAL` or `SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL` to determine the orientation of the JProgressBar.

For painting the text vertically, I found [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0259.html) which gives two examples. The first one prints the characters "right side up". It does this by getting all the characters from the string and looping over them, painting each one and incrementing the y value. The second example prints the characters sideways, using AffineTransform to rotate the graphics context 90 degrees, then painting the string.